# Почему меня нет в списке участников, объявивших вопрос требующим правки, если я оставлял тревогу по той же причине?

Tags: поддержка, закрытие-вопросов, тревоги

Я оставляю тревогу к вопросу по причине непонятной сути вопроса. Через несколько минут около вопроса появляется обозначение `[требует правки]` и под самим вопросом написано: "объявлен столько-то минут назад требующим правки участниками..." и далее идёт список участников, **в котором меня нет**. "... так как непонятна суть вопроса".

[Вот](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1018862/344284) пример такого вопроса, хотя подобное случалось и ранее:

Почему так происходит и как формируется этот список?

Comment: Я подобные случаи видел, когда в очередях проверки слишком долго читал вопрос. За то время пока я читал, пятый голос за закрытие уходил, мне же как лишнему проверка засчитывалась, но не показывалась. У вас случай похож?

Comment: @AK Наверное, нет. Но, как оказалось, причина в другом.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Потому что отображаются только те, кто проголосовал за закрытие:

[image: скриншот голоса]

А ты не проголосовал, а поставил тревогу, отправляющую вопрос в соответствующую очередь:

[image: скриншот тревоги]

Для того, чтобы голосовать за закрытие, [нужно иметь репутацию не менее 3000](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions).